# Chrome Startup Pages broken

Tags: google-chrome

Ever since [v39.0.2171.99](http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.com/2015/01/stable-channel-update.html), whenever Chrome opens, even from a fresh instance, it will reload the tabs when it closed last, instead of opening the [startup pages](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95314).

[image: Startup Pages]

Is there any fix for this?

Comment: I guess this is reported here. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=447046

Answer (score 0):

Quickest and easiest way is to download and install the free version of CCleaner, just untick all the cleaning options other than the Chrome ones! Clean it and all will be back to normal.

I just did that and it works :)

Comment: This really isn't detailed or long enough to merit a full answer. Can you expand upon this?